# Редактирование разнородных данных

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Есть некая коллекция интерфейсов

```
public interface ITask
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    void CreateTask();
    void EditTask();
    void Run();
}
```

Классов их реализующих будет несколько, и они будут несколько отличаться, настолько, что для редактирования не удается сделать обобщенное окно - и для каждого приходится делать отдельную вьюху. Пока прикостылил так (для примера из одного класса):

```
public void EditTask()
{
     var w = new CreatePicturePostingTaskWindow();
     w.DataContext = this;
     w.Show();
}
```

Пробовал пробрасывать мессенджером

```
Messenger.Default.Send(new EditPicturePostingTask(ref t));
```

Но все равно получается несколько многословно и некрасиво.

Наверняка кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей, и решил ее более толково, и сможет дать мне пару советов.

**P.S.** Еще одна побочная проблема - использование одной и той же вьюхи как для добавления нового элемента, так и для редактирования - приходится приделывать некрасивые костыли для выбора режима работы.

Comment: Вообще-то на самом деле делается ещё хуже. Для каждого класса в приложении регистрируется своя вьюха. `EditTask` должен извлечь из этого реестра нужную вьюху. Так что малословно вряд ли получится, а больше слов запросто. Какие там могут быть костыли? Переменная тира `bool` включает/выключает возможности редактирования в зависимости от режима. Часто её даже прибиндить можно к элементам формы

Comment: Ну костыли в моем архитектурном решении просто) Спасибо. Я просто думал есть какое-то изящное решение, о котором я не знаю, ан нет, никаких чудесных примочек не наблюдается.